# Do transations guarantee atomic execution of statements (in a programing sense)?

Tags: database

I have a database with tables: `users` and `relations` (between users). I want to add a relation between users only if both users exist. But between checking users and adding relationship one user might delete his account and in this case I want the second operation to fail. It wouldn't be a problem if both operations did execute atomicly (in programming sense). Do transactions guarantee that? I know that they guarantee that either all operations are executed or none with rollbacks (I recently learned that is also called atomicity), but do they also guarantee normal atomicity? And if they don't how can I solve the problem above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending, whether you are using RDBMS, but Primary keys and foreign keys should resolve your problem. users (PK) -> relations (FK).
Transactions will provide then, that first relation will be added, then user deletion handled.

Now the question is what do you mean by "deleting user".
If you mean to actually delete row in the database - then you can "delete cascade" e.g. [mysql](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) in order to remove both relation, and user. Alternatively - if you want to prevent user from being deleted, if there are any attached relations (which is what I understand you want to happen) - your PK-FK relation will provide it for you i.e. you first would need to delete all the attached relations, in order to delete user.